# Can cyclic and simplicial objects be related in a similar way to how the species of linear orders is the derivative of the species of cyclic orders?

Tags: co.combinatorics, ct.category-theory, simplicial-stuff, cyclic-homology

The derivative of a combinatorial species $S: core(FinSet) \to core(FinSet)$ is given by $S^\prime [N] = S[N\sqcup 1]$. Intuitively, an $S^\prime$-structure is built by introducing a "hole" to the set of building blocks and then building an $S$-structure incorporating the hole. If one builds a cyclic order with one vertex being a "hole", this can be identified with a linear order on the rest of the vertices. One says that the species of linear orders is the derivative of the species of cyclic orders.

The *augmented* simplex category admits strikingly natural characterizations. For example, the augmented simplex category is the free *(monoid)-pointed* monoidal category: it co-classifies monoids in strict monoidal categories via monoidal functors.

The augmented simplex *2-category* is freely generated by the walking span under the operations of taking pushouts and adjoints.

These characterizations are quite useful in some applications. It would be nice to have a one-liner characterizing the Connes cycle category $\Lambda$, too. The self-duality of $\Lambda$ gives me the feeling that it might admit an even more natural universal characterization than its would-be "derivative" $\Delta_{\alpha}$. I am sweeping some details under the rug concerning the difference between $\Lambda$ and "$\Lambda_{\alpha}$", if an augmented cycle category has even been described. I think I have painted enough of a picture.

Is this idea buried in the literature somewhere? I would love a sharper compression of $\Lambda$. Thank you!

Comment: If $\Delta_{\alpha} : 2Cat$ is freely generated by $\{ [0]\leftarrow [-1] \rightarrow [0]\}$ under the operations of pushouts and adjoints, then $\Delta_{\alpha}^{op} : 2Cat$ is generated by $\{ [0]\rightarrow [-1] \leftarrow [0]\}$ under pullbacks and adjoints, right? Perhaps the self-duality of $\Lambda_{\alpha}$ suggests a description as a 2-category generated by taking adjoints, pushouts, and pullbacks? Hmm.